# Why am I not earning the "Revival" badge?

Tags: support, badges

The badge "Revival" is a bronze badge that can be obtained after 30 days of your answer being accepted with a score 2+, and for [this answer,](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/383048/how-can-i-disable-quick-chat-in-among-us-on-the-nintendo-switch/383181#383181) I haven't earned the Revival badge. May I get the Revival badge, or what shall I answer another question with a score of two or more to get it in the next month?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah, I see the confusion. The criteria for that badge is that you must be the first to answer a question, answer it 30+ days after it being asked, and have that answer be accepted with a score of 2+. Your answer for that question was written two days after the question was asked, and thus is not eligible for the Revival badge.

Comment: The answer doesn't have to be accepted for Revival, just posted 30 days after the question and to be the first to score 2+ upvotes.

Comment: Iirc the badge used to be called Necromancer

Comment: @Unionhawk Necromancer's the tougher, silver-badge version: *Answer a question more than 60 days later with score of 5 or more*.

Comment: @Robotnik Oh, good catch! I misread the description, too!